# jQuery ui triggers resize event but does't change the div's width

Tags: jquery-ui, durandal, jquery-ui-resizable

I have the following view:

```
<aside id="key-panel" class="ui-widget-content">
   <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</aside>
```

I'm injecting the above view into the main html file using durandal.js. So when the view is attached, i execute the following code:

```
   $('#key-panel')
            .resizable({
                handles: 'w',
                animate: true,
                start: function (e, ui) {
                },
                resize: function (e, ui) {
                    console.log('resizing');
                },
                stop: function (e, ui) {
                }
            })
```

When trying to resize the container i can see the mouse cursor being changed, as well as the resize event being fired; However, the actual container doesn't change its size.
Below is the Html that is created by durandal and jquery ui

```
<div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="views/keyPanel" data-active-view="true">
    <aside id="key-panel" class="ui-widget-content ui-resizable ui-draggable"style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: auto;">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div></aside>
</div>
```

I've noticed that the aside element doesn't have the width property in the style attribute.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong. I tried to make the container draggable and it worked, it's only the resizable functionality that is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem, but I recommend you to put a extra div in all your views. I don't know why, but during the composition some styles are changed. Maybe, adding a extra div in the template can solve your problem.

```
<div>
 <aside id="key-panel" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
 </aside>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't do the job. I still can't do any resizing. Thanks anyway